# Dynamic routing problem when invoking site from remote host

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Hell,

I have error handling for my mvc app configured in the simplified way below (**globals.asax**):

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();

         Response.Clear();         
         RouteData routeData = new RouteData();
         routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error");
         routeData.Values.Add("action", "General");            
         routeData.Values.Add("exc", exception);
         Server.ClearError();
         using (ErrorController errorController = new ErrorController())
         {
            ((IController)errorController).Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));
         }         
      }
```

Above, I'm dynamically creating route for the controller. It is useful, because I can pass the Exception object to controller action. This is just simplified version shown above, because normally I'm creating different routes for various exception types. I have **NO** static route defined especially for error handling in function **RegisterRoutes**. This function is untouched:

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
 {
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = ""}
            );
 }
```

My simplified controller looks like that:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
   {
      public ActionResult General(Exception exc)
      {
         ViewData["ErrorDetails"] = exc.ToString();
         return View("Error");
      }
}
```

Suppose, I have an error prone site:

*http://**localhost**/app/site/wtf*.

When I'm testing error handling locally, everything is fine. **ErrorController** is invoking **General** action, and this action renders **Error** view.

But when I'm invoking this error prone site from another host, for example, the application is deployed on nice.host.org server:

*http://**nice.host.org**/app/site/wtf*,

I'm getting such exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The view 'Error' or its master was not found. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/DynamicPage/Error.aspx
~/Views/DynamicPage/Error.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Error.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Error.ascx
~/Views/DynamicPage/Error.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult.FindView(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass6.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

What is going on ? How to make this work as expected ?

**UPDATE**

I'll provide some additional info just in case.

I'm using **razor view engine**. In the properties window of **Error.cshtml** view file, I've tried to set **Build Action** to **None** or to **Content**, but the behaviour of the app is still broken, despite which option is selected.

When it comes to pages section in main web.config file, it looks following:

```
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

and in the second web.config:

```
<pages
        validateRequest="false"
        pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <controls>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
      </controls>
</pages>
```

I'll appreciate any clue.

Regards

Comment: Are you hosting the site with the same server (e.g. IIS) on both your local and the hosted example? If you are not that might explain why you are getting an error in one but not the other.

Comment: Yes, the server is the same and the server settings are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the problem. I had to add such entry to web.config

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

There are three error modes in customErrors configuration: **On**, **Off** and **RemoteOnly**. The mode attribute specifies whether custom errors are enabled, disabled, or shown only to remote clients.

**On** - Specifies that custom errors are enabled. If no defaultRedirect attribute is specified, users see a generic error. The custom errors are shown to the remote clients and to the local host.

**Off** - Specifies that custom errors are disabled. The detailed ASP.NET errors are shown to the remote clients and to the local host.

**RemoteOnly** - Specifies that custom errors are shown only to the remote clients, and that ASP.NET errors are shown to the local host.

By **default**, the mode value is set to **RemoteOnly**.

Previously I had no config entry for customErrors in web.config, so default mode was turned on. When there was an error in a view itself, it was resulting in a redirect to default customErrors url - Error.aspx, which was in turn resulting in previously shown exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The view 'Error' or its master was not found. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/DynamicPage/Error.aspx
~/Views/DynamicPage/Error.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Error.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Error.ascx
~/Views/DynamicPage/Error.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml
```

This exception was next handled by ErrorController and shown to user.

Now it's ok.